# How to ovewrite plugins configuration with user configuration?

Tags: tmux, tmux-plugin-manager

I'd like to use tmux-pain-control but I have C-h set to move window left, and since tpm says it needs to go at the very bottom of the configuration file, the plugins always overwrite my configuration.

How can I make it so I can overwrite the plugin configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to, you can still put your overriding commands *after* the `run` of tpm. The "need" is just to ensure the plugins work as intended and so avoid spurious issues, but if you know the consequences of your commands it is not a problem.

Or you can edit `~/.tmux/plugins/tmux-pain-control/pain_control.tmux`,
find the line

```
tmux bind-key C-h select-pane -L
```

and comment it out with a `#` at the start of the line.